# Specify a relative path as infile for a .ctl

Tags: oracle, sql-loader

I can't seem to find a way to specify a relative path for my infile when using sql loader.

I'm running it through a command line and this is what it looks like:

```
C:\app\...in\sqlldr.exe userid=user/pass 
control="C:\User...DATA_DATA_TABLE.ctl" log="C:\User...DATA_DATA_TABLE.log"
 bad = "C:\User...DATA_DATA_TABLE.bad" discard = "C:\User...DATA_DATA_TABLE.dsc"
```

(I've added carriage returns just for the readability on here, the command i use is one line)

And this works, it's will start inserting stuff in the table IF the path to my infile in .ctl is absolute like "C:\Usertemp\example.ldr"

My ctl was generated autmatically by sqldeveloper. And i just changed the path to this:

```
OPTIONS (ERRORS=50)
LOAD DATA 
INFILE 'AI_SLA_DATA_DATA_TABLE.ldr' "str '{EOL}'" <-- i'm trying to get relative path here but doesn't work
APPEND
CONTINUEIF NEXT(1:1) = '#'
INTO TABLE "USER"."DATA"
...other sqldeveloper generated stuff
```

The .ldr file is in the same directory as the .ctl file. Is it possible to get the path of the ctl? I'm pretty sure he searches for the .ldr file next to the sqlldr.exe instead of the ctl.

Any tips to do this? I can't find answers on docs.oracle.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I've never tried adding a relative path to the .ctl file, but for me it works fine as a command-line argument, e.g.

```
C:\app\...in\sqlldr.exe userid=user/pass 
control="DATA_DATA_TABLE.ctl" log="DATA_DATA_TABLE.log"
 bad = "DATA_DATA_TABLE.bad" discard ="DATA_DATA_TABLE.dsc"
data="AI_SLA_DATA_DATA_TABLE.ldr"
```

Comment: That would work for me but can you put this inside: "str '{EOL}'" It appears at the end of the infile in the .ctl